# Context Free Grammar for Summation notation

Tags: context-free-grammar, notation

I want to write a context-free grammar production rules for deriving Mathematical functions. I wanted to start with summation notation for now. I started writing with a function signature of summation but got confused how to go further with the approach. Can anybody tell me how to incorporate this?

thanks

Comment: It's hard to tell you how to "incorporate" the production without seeing what you want to incorporate it into, presumably a standard expression grammar. (If not, I suggest you start with a standard expression grammar such as the one in the bison manual, and then figure out how to add function calls and similar, such as your summation notation.)

Comment: ∑ i= a to b for function F(i)

Here I have put it down as a function. Now I wish to derive production rules for this function. This is what I came up with. Is it correct or needed to be refined?


SUMMATION(i,a,b,F(i))

S → Func(A)

Func → SUM  |  INTEGRATION  |  SIN  |  COS …….
A → BZCZDZE
Z  → ,
B → alphabets*
C → integers*
D → integers*
E → Func(A)

Comment: Snapshot of the expression is attached with the below comment. Look for clarity

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like the following:

```
<number> -> 0 | 1 | ... | 8 | 9
<expression> -> <number> | <expression> + <expression>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but not like this. Actually I am considering a function as SUM(i,a,b,F(i)), where i is index, a is the starting index and b is the end index and F(i) is the function to be added. Function can be anything . So I want to write grammar production rules for this approach

Comment: @FaridHaq: Like what then? Could you give a simpler example or explain more?